# Lowering and raising tensor indices without using metric tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, tensors

Is it possible to lower and raise tensor indices using non-metric tensor?
For example if we define non-singular tensor ${a_{ij}}$ such that ${a_{ij}a^{jk}=\delta^{k}_{i}}$ and it is not metric tensor. Then take another tensor ${b^{t}\in V}$ and ${b_{t}\in V^{*}}$. Is that right: ${b_{t}=a_{ti}b^{i}}$, ${a^{jt}b_{t}=a_{ti}a^{ik}b^{j}}$, ${b^{j}=a^{jt}b_{t}}$?

Comment: You may have defined a metric tensor. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor

Comment: Is the metric tensor the only one non-singular tensor?

Comment: No, of course not. But look at the definition of a metric tensor in that link I posted

Comment: I'm not that into this material but I think that the metric tensor is defined for all coordinates systems(generalized definition). If we have only one coordinate frame and there the metric tensor is ${g_{ij}}$ can we use another non-singular tensor ${a_{ij}}$ to transform from covariant to contravariant components?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You don’t even have to use a tensor to alter indices. While it’s not done often, the Levi-Civita symbol can be used in certain physics contexts.
The LC symbol, $\epsilon_{i,j,k}$= $\epsilon^{i,j,k}$ is anti symmetric in its components. It takes in values of 0,1,-1 in every coordinate frame so it isn’t actually a tensor (hence calling it a symbol like the Christoffel symbol).
To make it a tensor, you have to multiply it by $\sqrt{|g|}$

For more information, visit the link below: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153282/raising-and-lowering-indices-of-the-levi-civita-epsilon-symbol-in-two-dimensions